# callback not working in ie 10 browser

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Here i am calling a servlet. Get call happens to the servlet, when `document.getElementById('testURL').value + '?opn=getKey&rand='+ Math.random();` is done. This returns the key and a call to the `callback()` function. In IE 9 this works fine. But in ie 10 it requires some pause after this call. So i had to put the below alerts. Can anyone help me to know why is this issue in IE10? And how to resolve this? Alerting is a not a right way to do it. Thanks in advance!

```
function getKey(){ 
        var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]; 
        var scriptEmt =document.createElement('script'); 
        scriptEmt.type='text/javascript'; 
        scriptEmt.src=document.getElementById('testURL').value + 'opn=getKey&rand='+ Math.random(); 
        if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 10.0") != -1){
            alert("alert1..");
            alert("alert2....");
        }
        headID.appendChild(scriptEmt);          
    }   

function callback(){ 
...
...
}
```

Comment: A better way of pausing would be the `setTimeout` function because alerts require user interaction.

Comment: But i am not calling the callback(). The servlet call does return the key and calls the callback() without timeout.

Comment: @user11111111 if you _need_ to freeze the browser for a while, I suggest using synchronous javascript rather than alerts. You can control the delay this way (up to network delay jitter).

Comment: but, if you want synchronous loading, do not emulate it with timeouts, ever.

Comment: Your problem is that the callback is not executed after the script is loaded right? I tried your set up, but couldn't see the any problem with it. Can you please post the content of the servlet response? If it's possible you could use jQuery and make an ajax call to your servlet.

Comment: Can you check if you are not calling inside the callback stuff that is not already loaded? Like a library that is made to be loaded asynchronously in a script tag further down.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code the problem looks to be that

```
headID.appendChild(scriptEmt);
```

is being executed before the scripts "src" attribute has actually finished populating, which means that when the script element the actually gets appended to the document doesn't have the "src" attribute, which means that there's effectively no code to actually execute in the scriptEmt element. This also explains why the callback never gets called.

The better solution would be to use an ajax request to get the key. Use ajax to load the key value from the servlet, and once you have the key value only then should you create the script tag and append it to the document. This way you will ensure that the script src attribute has a value, and once that gets appended to the document the script will be executed and the callback called.

As to specifically why this affects IE10, I can only guess, but I would hazard a guess at the changes that have been made to IE10. Microsoft made a lot of changes with IE10, many of them around javascript performance, so it's *possible* that things are just running a fraction of a second quicker resulting in the behaviour you're seeing. Like I said that's just a guess, I have no "real" data or facts to back this up!

Comment: I just tried to load the static js file instead of a servlet call as below  function getKey(){ var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]; var scriptEmt =document.createElement('script'); scriptEmt.type='text/javascript'; scriptEmt.src="preview16.ar.com/Svc/js/test.js";; headID.appendChild(scriptEmt); calltest(); }

Comment: Here when i check in network capture - The test.js is successfully loaded. And i can see the js file and its contents in Response body of the URL preview16.ar.com/Svc/js/test.js. My test.js file contents looks like this:  function calltest(){ alert("I am in test"); } But when i call calltest() in getKey() after headID.appendChild(scriptEmt); statement it says ERROR - SCRIPT5009: 'calltest' is undefined

Comment: Please can you create a jsfiddle for this? I'm struggling to visualise the code!